# Hybrid cars - are they good

Tags: battery-charging

I hope this is not too much outside this forum, but...

Up to now - and recently more frequently, I see advertising and promising talk about the new breed of hybrid cars and all-electrical cars (like the Tesla).

But what I dislike (from what I know about this topic), is the fact that they somehow must be much more polluting than told.

This should be from the fact You cannot charge a battery without quite a loss, like - say,  only 60% of the of energy used is stored in the battery (so 40% in this example is lost). This is like using 10 Kilowatt/h to charge a 60 Kilowatt battery/h - 40Kw/h is lost.

This is not green energy, but rather waste because the electrical power are generated by coal, oil and atomic which all pollute.

So the picture with a happy person driving around in the city without pollution must an illusion for selling those hybrid cars, because the only thing in reality is that the car manufactures has just moved the pollution away from the car itself.

But have I overseen something?

Comment: To answer this comprehensively isn't really possible in stackexchange. Also, this is not an electronic design question, so this is not the correct place to ask. Maybe ask on reddit?

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of your question:

Batteries can be charged much more efficient than your assumption. The typical internal resistance of modern lithium batteries is in the order of some milliohms.

Just as an example, consider a single lithium cell with 100\$m\Omega\$ internal resistance (which would be rather large) and a capacity of 2Ah. Let's do some worst case calculation here. Assume the battery is charged it with a current of 2A to get it up to full capacity fast (1C charging is not really healthy for the battery). The battery is empty and starts at 3V.

So you force a current of 2A into 3V over a 100\$m\Omega\$ resistance, you would need a power of \$P_{total} = 2A \times 3V+100m\Omega \times (2A)^2 = 6.4W\$

Of that power the portion over the internal resistance is wasted to heat, so:
\$P_{wasted} = 100m\Omega \times (2A)^2 = 0.4W\$

Which would give us the efficiency of the battery to:
$$\eta_{battery}=1-\frac{P_{wasted}}{P_{total}} \approx 94\%$$

And that is already a worst case scenario, the efficiency increases as charging currents used tend to be lower than 1C and the internal resistance should be smaller. And the voltage of the battery goes up during the charging process, which increases efficiency further.

The charging circuit can reach efficiencies well over 90% as well for large battery packs. So in the end you have an efficiency which would probably be in the region of 85% to 90%.

---

(snip here to remove off-topic content)

As for the rest (which is off-topic), my view:

There are calculations on how bad those cars pollute the environment based on different sources. If they are not charged with renewable energy they can be worse than traditional cars. But then for the "normal" human it's also a matter where the pollution happens, if it's in the city, right in your face, you don't like it (traditional car). If it's somewhere else you won't notice it (electric car), so they can improve air quality in cities, which is also a good thing.

Comment: Powering an electric car from a conventional plant is still likely to be more efficient - large coal plant efficiencies can be over 30% vs maybe 25% for a small petrol engine. Thermodynamics don't scale well to small cylinder engines.

Comment: For every charge even the best batteries die a little, thus decreasing efficiency. The 90% eff. must be for brand new batts.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you are. Firstly, as you are talking about efficiency, let's take a look at combustion engines. The most efficiency one (probably a diesel one) will roughly generates 50% of the power it uses. By the side, an electrical one will be up to 95%. So, considering the charging losses on battery, assuming the 40% you gave me it's true, the electrical motor is still more efficient. And in fact, since mainly of electrical generators use renewable sources it's very less pollutant than fossil combustibles. Of course it's not clean, but a lot more than oil derivatives. Here in Brazil, for example, about 75% of our energy is hydroelectric which can be considered a clean one.

Do a little research and you will find tons of another advantages of electrical cars. The future is happening ;)

Comment: You're forgetting to multiply by the power station and transmission grid efficiency.

Comment: Thx, but so we also are forgetting to consider the transport costs of the combustible and they're sure less efficiency! It's a complicated equation, since we have mechanical stress on vehicles, climate dependents, travel distance...

Comment: Btw, all the things are electrical related is about 90% of efficiency. A transformer may reach above 99%! The less efficiency process is on generation which is mostly a mechanical process ;P.  Some combustible engines may have values lower than 30%. As an electrical engineering I can't see how can a combustible engine may be better, may a mechanical one can show me good points.

Comment: Also, we are not considering the process on a refinery, extraction of oil and many others. Neither to build a power plant, maintenance costs of both...

Comment: Dont't forget that some(most) hybrid cars, does charge the batt. driving on the road with the petrol engine. So there we have a pollutive (and efficient) charge method.